# Use case of overloading address-of operator

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, std, addressof

I think it's dangerous to overload the address-of operator `&`, because it's easy to overlook the use of [`std::addressof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) in implementing templates that actually need it. Still, I'm wondering what would be a proper use case of overloading this operator. Particularly, is there any class (template) in the standard library that has done this? Finally, since `std::addressof()` is introduced since C++11, is there any way to take the address of an object that has this overloading in C++03?

Comment: You might use the given implementation in C++03: [std::addressof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof)

Answer (score 2):

`&` is often overloaded when building smart pointer classes, as it makes them easier to use: more often than not you want the bare managed pointer, *not* the address of the smart pointer object.

Neglecting the evolutionary backwater that was `std::auto_ptr`, smart pointer classes such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` have been introduced into the standard since C++11. `std::addressof` was introduced in that standard since taking the *real* address of an object is occasionally required.

A possible implementation of `std::addressof` is trivial but is smelly due to the amount of casting required; a possible implementation is<sup>1</sup>

```
template< class T >
T* addressof(T& arg) 
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(
               &const_cast<char&>(
                  reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>(arg)));
}
```

Other more exotic uses of overloading `&` are for supporting EBNF grammar parsers. Boost Spirit does this with remarkable alacrity.

---

<sup>1</sup> Quoting from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof

Comment: Neither `std::unique_ptr` nor `std::shared_ptr` overload the `&` operator so I don't see what your point is.

Comment: The standard smart pointers overload `*` and `->`,not `&`

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way is the `std::addressof()` in C++11 or later, or its implementation for earlier versions, see above:

```
template< class T >
T* addressof(T& arg) 
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(
               &const_cast<char&>(
                  reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>(arg)));
}
```

Comment: I can't quote chapter and verse, but I *think* that is formally undefined behaviour. That is *why* `std::addressof` was added to the standard; most implementations can just use the code you have, but if it doesn't work, they have have to create a `__addressof__` keyword and have the compiler recognize it (or similar approach).  This is the same reason `offsetof` is standardized.

Comment: you mean the implementation I provided is undefined? This is the actual implementation of addressof or very similar one!

Comment: Yes, I mean the code you provide is undefined.  The standard library is part of the C++ implementation.  As such, it is fine for it to rely on the behaviour of the particular compiler (remember "undefined" doesn't mean "won't work", it means "the standard doesn't guarantee it will work").  For those people trying to write portable code OTOH, relying on the behaviour of the compiler is a bad idea (particularly as, if the compiler behaviour changes, they can change the library to match).

Comment: @MartinBonner If casting references behave the same as pointers (as I would intuit), it is well-defined. `offsetof` does more than casting, it also requires pointer arithmetic, which is undefined on anything other than arrays

Comment: It is noted however, that a `constexpr` version requires compiler support